# PhalconPHP response redirect in micro application not working

Tags: php, redirect, response, phalcon

I'm testing the following PhalconPHP micro app code from http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/micro.html

```
<?php 
use Phalcon\Mvc\Micro,
Phalcon\Events\Manager as EventsManager;

//Create a events manager
$eventManager = new EventsManager();

//Listen all the application events
$eventManager->attach('micro', function($event, $app) {

if ($event->getType() == 'beforeExecuteRoute') {
    if ($app->session->get('auth') == false) {

        $app->response->redirect("/");

        //Return (false) stop the operation
        return false;
    }
}

});

$app = new Micro();

//Bind the events manager to the app
$app->setEventsManager($eventManager);
```

The problem is that it never redirects, it's like `$app->response->redirect("/");` is not working.

If I try to return `$app->response->redirect("/");` the event chain doesn't stop and it returns the original requested url and not the one in the redirect.

Any ideas?

[UPDATE - SOLUTION]

Check this code out: https://github.com/cmoore4/phalcon-rest/blob/develop/index.php

I've solved using the same logic of the commented begin handler in the above code. 
It's does not fix the response not working but it's what I needed.
Hope it can help someone else.

Comment: Could it be a mod_rewrite problem?

Comment: I don't think so, if I try to use the same code somewhere else it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$app->response->redirect("/")->sendHeaders();
```

You need to send proper headers to make a redirect possible. Try the above code.

Comment: Never tried it, I've solved with the UPDATE above. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your redirect as follows:

```
$app->response->redirect("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to the root scope. You should try this code:

```
$app->response->redirect()->sendHeaders();
```

Otherwise, you can specific you link request as below:

```
$app->response->redirect('/sample/link')->sendHeaders();
```

Hope this would help.